# Descarga del fichero en el servidor al generar zip con zipArchive

Tags: php, zip

Estoy generando un archivo .zip en php con zipArchive y me surge un problema y es que aunque el archivo se descargue automáticamente en el PC, también se me almacena internamente en el servidor. Seguramente sea una tontería pero no doy con la tecla, a ver si podéis ayudarme. Os dejo el código de generación del zip. Muchas gracias

if($num_docs!=0){

```
    $archivoZip = $zip->open( $zipname, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE );
    $zip->open($zipname, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE );
    $zip->addEmptyDir($exp['num_exp']);
    do
    {           
        if($archivoZip==true){
            $zip->addFile("documentacion/" . $exp['num_exp']."/" . $doc['fichero'], $exp['num_exp']."/" . $doc['fichero']);     
        }
    }while($doc = mysql_fetch_assoc($docs));
    $zip->close();
}

///DESCARGANDO EL ZIP
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: Yo lo que hago es localizar la carpeta donde lo guarda en el servidor, y después de del "header()" de descarga, hago un unlink al fichero del servidor, así no me los acumula.

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto una función que yo utilizo cotidianamente y en la cual te indico como eliminar el archivo que se genera en tu servidor

```
public function download_zip($route){
        if (file_exists($route)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($route));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($route));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($route);
            unlink($route);//Esta línea destruye el elemento zip que se genera
            exit;
        }

    }
```